# Upload a file to a cloud server, then save that path in mongo.

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, mongodb

I need to load images to a cloud service, Backblaze B2, then save that path in my Mongo db for later reference. Can I make a call with the browser to save the image in the cloud service, then when that is done, get a callback that sends that to my server to save into mongodb using Node? I think I can see how this can happen but I dont want to put a bunch of time into something that may not work. 
I can see how the image sends to B2, but can the browser get the response? Then save to a request?

How can this be implemented?

Comment: most likely you need to glue the two pieces using a server-side script like PHP because most binary-upload APIs (that i've seen) don't support CORS or JSONP responses; so while JS can upload, it's not allowed to see the result, which precludes sending a new piece of info from it to mongo. if your api is "ajaxable" then it's no problem to handle it all client-side, but typically that's not the case...

Comment: Here is a link to the api : [link](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_upload_file.html), it does have a response and appears to give back data. I am unsure what you mean that if my api is ajaxable. my stack is meen stack (ejs vs angular)